Unit testing Asyncio ensure future
I have an async method which is basically used for making callback requests. I want to test this method and write unit tests. But I'm facing some issue while doing so. Can anyone point me to the right direction?
async def make_callback(
    async_call_back_request: AsyncCallbackRequest, url=None, url_suffix=None
):
    if not (url or _config.default_callback_url):
        return
    elif not url:
        url = _config.default_callback_url

    asyncio.ensure_future(
        _callback(async_call_back_request, url=url, url_suffix=url_suffix)
    )
async def _callback(
    async_call_back_request: AsyncCallbackRequest, url, url_suffix=None
):
    try:
        res = httpx.post(
            f"{url.rstrip('/')}{url_suffix}",
            headers={"content-type": "application/json"},
            content=async_call_back_request.model_dump_json(),
            timeout=_config.default_callback_timeout,
        )

        res.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        _logger.error(f"Error during callback: {e}")

This is what I did so far
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_make_callback():
    async_call_back_request = AsyncCallbackRequest(
        header=AsyncCallbackRequestHeader(
            message_id="123",
            message_ts="2021-05-01T12:00:00Z",
            action="test_action",
            status=StatusEnum.succ,
        ),
        message={"key": "value"},
    )

    url = "http://test.com/callback"
    url_suffix = "/suffix"

    with patch(
        "openg2p_spar_mapper_api.controllers.async_mapper_controller.httpx.post"
    ) as mock_post:
        mock_response = MagicMock()
        mock_response.raise_for_status.return_value = None
        mock_post.return_value = mock_response

        # Execute the make_callback method
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(
            AsyncMapperController.make_callback(
                async_call_back_request, url, url_suffix
            )
        )

        # Wait for the make_callback task to complete
        await task

        # This line waits for all other spawned tasks to complete
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
        )

        # Check if httpx.post was called as expected
        mock_post.assert_called_once_with(
            f"{url.rstrip('/')}{url_suffix}",
            headers={"content-type": "application/json"},
            content=async_call_back_request.model_dump_json(),
            timeout=30,
        )

It’s returning
FAILED tests/test_async_mapper_controller.py::test_make_callback - AssertionError: expected call not found.

I was able to finally resolve it using the below line.
# This line waits for all other spawned tasks to complete
        await asyncio.gather(*[t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()])

Updated unit test
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_make_callback():
    async_call_back_request = AsyncCallbackRequest(
        header=AsyncCallbackRequestHeader(
            message_id="123",
            message_ts="2021-05-01T12:00:00Z",
            action="test_action",
            status=StatusEnum.succ,
        ),
        message={"key": "value"},
    )

    url = "http://test.com/callback"
    url_suffix = "/suffix"

    with patch(
        "openg2p_spar_mapper_api.controllers.async_mapper_controller.httpx.post"
    ) as mock_post:
        mock_response = MagicMock()
        mock_response.raise_for_status.return_value = None
        mock_post.return_value = mock_response

        task = asyncio.ensure_future(
            AsyncMapperController.make_callback(
                async_call_back_request, url, url_suffix
            )
        )
        await task
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
        )

        mock_post.assert_called_once_with(
            f"{url.rstrip('/')}{url_suffix}",
            headers={"content-type": "application/json"},
            content=async_call_back_request.model_dump_json(),
            timeout=10,
        )

